# fastest-validator: validate two field to not be equal

Tags: javascript, express, validation

I use [fastest-validator](https://github.com/icebob/fastest-validator#equal) to validate an object like this:

```js
{
    "_id":"619e00c177f6ea2eccffd09f",
    "parent_id": "619e00c177f6ea2eccffd09f",
}
```

`_id` and `parent_id` must not be equal. How to check that?
I know `fastest-validator` has following validation for [equality](https://github.com/icebob/fastest-validator#equal). but I need to check the opposite.
(example for `type= "equal"`):

```js
const schema = {
    password: { type: "string", min: 6 },
    confirmPassword: { type: "equal", field: "password" }
}
const check = v.compile(schema);

check({ password: "123456", confirmPassword: "123456" }); // Valid
check({ password: "123456", confirmPassword: "pass1234" }); // Fail
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Meta information for custom validators](https://github.com/icebob/fastest-validator#meta-information-for-custom-validators):

> You can pass any extra meta information for the custom validators which is available via context.meta.

so I can compare any two field that I want. In my to compare `_id` and `parent_id` I can use this:

```js
const v = new Validator({
    useNewCustomCheckerFunction: true,
    messages: {
        notEqual: "_id and parent_id can not be equal"
    }
});

const editSchema = {
    _id: { type: "string" },
    parent_id: {
        type: "string",
        custom: (value, errors, schema, name, parent, context) =>{
            if (context.data._id === value) errors.push({type: "notEqual"})
            return value
        }
    }
};
```